# JFreeChart Stacked Area Chart not continous

Tags: jfreechart

I used the [`createStackedAreaChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createStackedAreaChart%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset,%20org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean%29), but the stacked area chart I got is not continous. There are gaps between categories (just look like stacked bar chart). But If I use `createAreaChart()` for the same dataset (`DefaultCategoryDataset`), the area chart is fine. What's wrong with the stacked area chart? I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that includes representative data and exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 2):

I got it. Somehow, I have to set the category margin to avoid the gaps in the chart. 
domainAxis.setCategoryMargin(0);

Comment: This solved my problem, when constructing `CombinedDomainCategoryPlot`

Answer (score 1):

Using the `CategoryDataset` returned by [`createDataset()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html#line.82) in [`BarChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html), the static factory method [`ChartFactory.createStackedAreaChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createStackedAreaChart%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset,%20org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) produces the following chart with no gaps. You should examine your data set critically.

[image: StackedAreaChart]

Comment: but if i use the same dataset to create area chart, the chart is fine. only when i create stacked area chart, it has the problem.

Comment: Hard to say why without seeing your data set.

Comment: Hey trashgod, the above stacked area chart demo 1, we can see the white vertical lines in the area chart. How should we avoid it? Thanks.

Comment: The visibility of the gridlines can be controlled from the `CategoryPlot`.

Comment: I set setDomainGridlinesVisible(false); but it is still there. and i think they are not gridlines.

Answer (score 0):

In StackedAreaRenderer.java, the coordinate of Path has decimals, path is discontinuous in ANTIALIAS. Modify StackedAreaRenderer#drawItem with Math.round like AreaRenderer.java.